# Use DataFrame row.index as input to lambda function result

Tags: pandas, lambda, duplicates, rename

I have a large dataframe, df_vol.
It has about 20 columns and 500k rows.
In the column named "FTID" three of the values are "###". Other than those three instances every other value in the "FTID" column is unique.
I want to search for and change each instance of "###" to be unique.
Either of these two options would be acceptable:

1. "###1", "###2", "###3", or
2. "###" + str(row_index) for each i.e. concatenate "###" with the row index

The code I have tried is:

```
df_vol["FTID"] = df_vol["FTID"].apply(lambda x: "###" if x == "###" else None)
```

I know the above code doesn't actually change anything, but I don't know how to make it pull only the row index or use an incremental number. I have tried so many different things but I'm a noob, and I'm stabbing in the dark.
It seems to me it should look like:

```
df_vol["FTID"] = df_vol["FTID"].apply(lambda x: "###" + df_vol.index.astype(str) if x == "###" else None)
```

but what little success I have had just returns something like this for the new values:

```
Int64Index([   423,    424,    425,    426,    427,    428,    429,    430,
```

Going to go collect up all my hair now and see if I can glue it back to my head ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index with `x.name`. I think you need something like:

```
df_vol["FTID"] = df_vol["FTID"].apply(lambda x: f"###{x.name}" if x == "###" else x)
```

(I didn't get why you would otherwise set the value to None since other values are unique... I think it should be unchanged when not equal to `###`)

###### Edit: `apply` works slightly differently when use on [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [Dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

In your case it would be best to create a function and apply it on your whole dataframe:

```
def myfunc(row):
    if row['FTID']=="###":
        row['FTID'] = f"###{row.name}"
    return row

df_vol = df_vol.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - when I tried as you suggested I got an error:

** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' **

Then I changed {x.name} to {x.index} and I ended up with a result that looks like this:

** ###<built-in method index of str object at 0x000001EF39EC3AF0> **

Still scratching my head on this. Ps. The reason I had "else None" in the original post is because I'm on a steep learning curve ;)

Comment: I see. I updated my answer, check it out!